# Fasttext representation for short phrase, but not for longer phrase containing the short one

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, fasttext

I'm using `Gensim` for loading the german `.bin` files from `Fasttext` in order to get vector representations for out-of-vocabulary words and phrases. So far it works fine and I achieve good results overall.
I am familiar with the `KeyError :'all ngrams for word <word> absent from model'.` Clearly the model doesn't provide a vector representation for every possible ngram combination.
But now I ran into a confusing (at least for me) issue.
I'll just give a quick example:
the model provides a representation for the phrase `AuM Wert`.
But when I want to get a representation for `AuM Wert 50 Mio. Eur`, I'll get the `KeyError` mentioned above. So the model obviously has a representation for the shorter phrase but not for the extended one.
It even returns a representation for `AuM Wert 50 Mio.Eur` (I just removed the space between 'Mio' and 'Eur')
I mean, the statement in the Error is simply not true, because the first example shows that it knows some of the ngrams. Can someone explain that to me? What don't I understand here? Is my understanding of ngrams wrong?

Heres the code:

```
from gensim.models.wrappers import FastText
model = FastText.load_fasttext_format('cc.de.300.bin')
model.wv['AuM Wert'] #returns a vector
model.wv['AuM Wert 50 Mio.EUR'] #returns a vector
model.wv['AuM Wert 50 Mio. EUR'] #triggers the error
```

Thanks in advance,
Amos

Comment: Can you show (by adding to your question) the exact code you're using to "get a representation" from the model for certain inputs, and show the output or errors the code triggers?

Comment: just updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain what's causing the behavior you're seeing, though I have a theory below.

But, take note that the current gensim behavior (through 3.7.1), of sometimes returning `KeyError: all ngrams for word <...> absent` for an OOV word, does not conform to the behavior of Facebook's original FastText implementation, and is thus considered a bug.

It should be fixed in the next release. You can read a [change note about the new compatible behavior](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md#out-of-vocab-word-handling).

So, in the near future with an up-to-date version of gensim, you will never see this `KeyError'.

In the meantime, factors that *might* explain your observed behavior include:

- It's not typical to pass space-delimited phrases to `FastText`. Further, usual tokenizations of training texts will only pass word-tokens *without* any internal whitespace. So for a typical model, there's no chance such space-containing phrases will have full-word vectors. And, none of their character-n-grams that contains spaces will map to n-grams seen during training, either. To the extent you get a vector at all in gensim 3.7.1 and earlier, it will be because some of the n-grams *not* containing spaces were seen in training. (Post 3.7.1, you will always get a vector, though it may be composed from random collisions of the query-word's novel n-grams with n-grams learned in training, or simply with randomly-initialized-but-never-trained vectors inside the model's n-gram hashtable.)
- N-grams are learned with a synthetic start-of-word prefix and end-of-word suffix – specifically the characters `<` and `>`. And the default n-gram size range is from 4 to 6 characters. So, your string `'AuM Wert'` will among its n-grams include `'<AuM'`, `'Wert'`, and `'ert>'`. (All of its other n-grams will include a space character, and thus couldn't possibly be in the set of n-grams learned during training on words without spaces.). But note that the longer phrase, on which you get the error, will *not* include the n-gram `'ert>'`, because the prior end-of-token has been replaced with a space. So, the shorter phrase's n-grams is *not* a proper subset of the larger phrase's n-grams – and the larger phrase could error where the shorter does not. (And your longer phrase without a space, that does not error, also includes a number of extra 4-6 character n-grams that may have been in training data, that the erroring phrase does not have.)

Comment: Wow that's definetly an illuminating answer! I should dive deeper into learning ngrams. Thanks a lot man! Once I've gained some new knowledge I'll drop it here in the comments section. Unfortunatley my upvote doesn't show publicy, since my reputation is less than 15.

Comment: `Post 3.7.1, you will always get a vector` I don' think that's true. I am using gensim 4.0.1, and with the `fasttext-wiki-news-subwords-300` model there are plenty of phrases that give "Key not present" KeyErrors, e.g. "new york", "social support" etc.

Comment: I'd have to know more about that model's parameters, & the code you're using to load the model & trigger the `KeyError`, & the full error message to comment more on what's happening. (Perhaps: a new question?) But: looking at the current (`gensim-4.0.1`+) code for `FastTextKeyedVectors.get_vector()`, a `KeyError` can only be generated if the model's `bucket` value is 0, meaning it has no subword info at all, so isn't a real/full FT vector set. (Are you sure you didn't load jsut the full-word vectors?)

Comment: Thanks! I am using `gensim.downloader.load()` for loading the fasttext model. Now I think the model may just not have subword for "new york" (while it does have "newyork" and "new-york"). Surprise to me, considering the size of its training corpora.

Comment: In https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/faqs.html it does mention `Currently the best approach to represent word phrases or sentence is to take a bag of words of word vectors. Additionally, for phrases like “New York”, preprocessing the data so that it becomes a single token “New_York” can greatly help`.

Comment: I personally avoid the indirection of `gensim.downloader`, as it may hide the original source, & may load/run other unversioned code outside the normal package-management process. (See https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/2283). Downloading raw data from original sources ensures you know what you've got, from the original creator, and in what exact local files/paths - and then also which methods were used to bring it into memory - all of which is unhelpfully hidden is using `api.load()`.

Comment: What makes you think the model has no subwords for the string '`new york'`? What code did you run to make that determination, and what output or error did it give? What's the type of the model you're operating on?

Comment: Having looked at <https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim-data/releases/tag/fasttext-wiki-news-subwords-300>, specifically the out-of-version-control `__init__.py` code that's download & run when you call `api.load("fasttext-wiki-news-subwords-300")`, I see that it only loads these vectors as a `KeyedVectors` object, which can only return vectors for exact full words in the vector-set. That is, the `api.load("fasttext-wiki-news-subwords-300")` code does **not** create a FastText-specific object, and so could never return a vector for an OOV word.

Comment: You're absolutely right! I have discovered this actually. Loading a local fasttext bin model has allowed for subwords and returned similar words for 'new york'. Thanks!!